# Python Element Tree find return none in some pom.xml

Tags: python, xml

I want to use add some elements to pom.xml. I want to use find to locate `<dependencies>`. But it return NONE when parse some pom.xml files. I compare those pom.xml and find those pom.xml files are not begin with `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>`, is it the root cause? How can I hadle those pom.xml files.

Python code:
`tree = Et.ElementTree()
 tree.parse("pom.xml")
 root = tree.getroot()
 dep_child = root.find("{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}dependencies")`

Comment: Can you double check your pom.xml files ? Are you sure all of them have the `dependencies` element?

Comment: I mean, the code you're showing seems okay (just tested on a sample pom.xml and it finds the dependencies section alright)

Comment: Yes, all pom.xml files have the `dependencies` element

Comment: Can you post an example file and your full code? It will be easier to help you if you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's an example pom.xml.`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>com.hhxx.pus</groupId>
    <artifactId>pus-pss</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>`

Comment: If I remove `<dependencyManagement>`, change `<dependencyManagement> <dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId> </dependency> </dependencies> </dependencyManagement>` to `dependencies> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId> </dependency> </dependencies>`, it works.

Comment: Seems I should use `dep_child = root.find("*//{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}dependencies")` for those pom.xml. So should I need use two method both?

Comment: Right, exactly, the `find` method looks only direct children of the element.

Comment: @elias, For those pom.xml which are not include `<dependencyManagement>`, `find("*//{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}dependencies")` will return None. Is it correct?

Comment: hm... maybe, i'm not sure because i always use lxml which is way better to do this kind of stuff. if you have that option, i highly recommend it. then it will be simply `tree.xpath('//dependencies')`

Comment: You can also use Parsel: https://github.com/scrapy/parsel which makes it even easier (disclaimer: I help maintain parsel)

Answer (score 0):

```
    dep_child = root.find(pre + "dependencies")
    if dep_child is None:
        logging.error("Cannot find dependencies element under the root object")
        dep_child = root.find("*//" + pre + "dependencies")
    if dep_child is None:
        logging.error("Cannot find dependencies element on pom.xml")
        return False
```

Try different parameter